# Is it possible to stop taskbar programs staying next to each other?

Tags: windows-7

I'm not talking about the grouping feature (where they are combined into one icon/thing.  I have mine set to 'never combine')

I am talking about the fact that similar programs put all their items next to each other, for example if I open a new firefox window, it doesn't go to the end of the list, it goes to the right of the other firefox window I have open.  This is irritating because years of using Windows XP means I instinctively look to the far right to find my newly opened browser window,email,calender item,etc.

I should mention that I have tried googling this, but all I get are instructions for turning the grouping (combining into one button) off, which is not what I am looking for.